# Strange names remote validation for MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a problem with mapping a hidden for remote validation.

I have this class:

```
[Remote("Check", "Route", AdditionalFields = "LanguageID", ErrorMessage = "Err")]
public string RouteToken { get; set; }

public string LanguageID { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.Hidden("Route.LanguageID", Model.Route.LanguageID)
```

Gets rendered:

```
<input id="Route_LanguageID" name="Route.LanguageID" type="hidden" value="SV">
```

And it posts strange values with ".\" in name so it doesnt map to my original class:

[image]

What might be wrong here? No idea why it adds \ to name

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to achieve? Which input do you want to validate exactly? Also, can you show the entire view? And, replace your hidden field with the following:

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Route.LanguageId)`

Comment: tried it, same thing gets posted, but the main issue is why the \ is in the name

Comment: You didn't answer the rest of my question. Please post your controller action, and your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was custom replacements in jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js file